# Searching in C# giving wrong results

Tags: c#, sql-server, wildcard

I have an Email text box through which i can perform search.If i type a_Scott results are emails that begin: a_Scott but i am getting
 a.scott,
 ajscott,
 arscott.
here is my code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.EmailAddress))
{
    var email = request.EmailAddress.IndexOf("*", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0
                ? request.EmailAddress.RemovePercentsign().ReplaceAsterikWithPercentSign()
                : request.EmailAddress + "%";

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", email.Trim()));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are using SQL LIKE operator.

If you take a look at LIKE [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), you can see that '_' character has special meaning and need to be escaped just like you are doing with percent sign.

> _ (underscore)  - Any single character.

To escape `_` character just use square brackets like so `[_]`.

So your query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE email LIKE '%a[_]Scott%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sql fiddle to clear up the understandings
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d88af/4